# One Tao Sign In (YOLO API) - Localization

Tags: google-signin

Does one tap sign in (YOLO API) has languages available besides english?

Unable to find such info here - https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web
Would appreciate amy info.

Answer (score 0):

Google One Tap will always use the preferred language settings of the Google user.

For legal reasons, Google One Tap doesn't allow 3P website to control the language. Otherwise, users may click the big blue button (with caption 'Continue as XXX') without understanding the GDPR message.